# Problem in removing 0b from binary output

Tags: python

i have written this function that converts a string in binary

```
def str_2_bin(message): 
        separator = ''
        binary = separator.join(map(bin,bytearray(message,'utf-8')))
        return binary 

print (str_2_bin('hi there'))
```

and this is the output of the string:

```
0b11010000b11010010b1000000b11101000b11010000b11001010b11100100b1100101
```

I want to know is there a way to remove all '0b'from this output binary string

Comment: Even if you remove all the `0b`s, your output is almost certainly still going to be wrong. `bin`'s output is variable-width. You're not going to be able to tell where each byte starts or ends.

Comment: Do you want to remove the ``0b`` from the output (i.e. after running the function), or do you want to fix the function?

Comment: You probably want to use `"{:08b}".format` instead of `bin`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica actually in my code i will provide (after removing '0b' ) output to hexlify function which will convert from left each nible into hex on its own (thats i am hopping to happen).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i want to remove '0b' from the output

Comment: @Olvin Roght ok i will try this method

Comment: @hunter Then your output will be ambiguous. Compare ``str_2_bin('P').replace('0b', '')`` and ``str_2_bin('(\x00').replace('0b', '')``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  thanks for these alternatives i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using replace function. Replace '0b' by ''.

```
def str_2_bin(message): 
        separator = ''
        binary = separator.join(map(bin,bytearray(message,'utf-8')))
        binary = binary.replace("0b","")
        return binary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to:

```
def str_2_bin(message): 
    separator = ''
    binary = separator.join(f"{x:08b}" for x in bytearray(message,'utf-8'))
    return binary
```

This formats each byte to a zero-padded binary string of length 8. That's the `08b` format sepcifier.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to not initialize `bytearray` just to iterate over charcodes: `"".join(f"{ord(x):08b}" for x in message)`

Comment: That will only work for the first 256 unicode chars.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Future Python versions might provide us with some `iterbytes` methods, tho: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/

Comment: @schwobaseggl it worked but it adds 0 padding after every byte

Comment: @hunter It adds zeroes **before** the ones that are shorter then 8.